# Migrate from bootstrap vuejs to vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue, vuetifyjs3

Would it be possible to migrate a project that currently uses bootstrap to vuetify?
That is to say change all the elements that you use. Would it be necessary to have the dependencies of the two libraries installed during the migration?

Comment: if the migration is done piecemeal, then of course you'd need both!!

Comment: You can migrate any project to whatever else. If you serve the app when both are used at the same time, of course you need to serve both dependencies. How else would it work?